# Programming CH552G

Tags: embedded, programming, microprocessor, breadboard, programmer

Stack Overflow isn't letting me have all the links I need here, so I put them all in [this google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C-h4nnqFIetByAsUok803PYZP_dpqGwQuxIWEBTKRro/edit?usp=sharing). Sorry about that!

This is my first solo embedded development project, and I can't seem to figure out how to program my chip!

My setup:
I'm using a CH552G chip mounted on a breakout board, purchased here (1), on a breadboard with what I understand to be the necessary peripherals.

[image: Show schematic here]

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to follow what this YouTuber(2) did, and I'm using part of his schematic.

[image: Schematic from Youtuber]

I tried to program it first on Windows using these instructions (3), but WCHISPTOOL never recognizes the device, so I can't program it.

I tried again on Linux using these instructions (4) and programming via `make flash` in [these examples](https://github.com/Blinkinlabs/ch554_sdcc.git), but the chip isn't recognized there either!

[image]

```
/Desktop/ch552tool/ch554_sdcc/examples/blink$ make flash
sdcc -c -V -mmcs51 --model-small --xram-size 0x0400 --xram-loc 0x0000 --code-size 0x3800 -I/home/zico/Desktop/ch552tool/ch554_sdcc/examples/../include -DFREQ_SYS=24000000  ../../include/debug.c
+ /usr/bin/sdcpp -nostdinc -Wall -std=c11 -I/home/zico/Desktop/ch552tool/ch554_sdcc/examples/../include -DFREQ_SYS=24000000 -obj-ext=.rel -D__SDCC_CHAR_UNSIGNED -D__SDCC_MODEL_SMALL -D__SDCC_FLOAT_REENT -D__SDCC=4_0_0 -D__SDCC_VERSION_MAJOR=4 -D__SDCC_VERSION_MINOR=0 -D__SDCC_VERSION_PATCH=0 -DSDCC=400 -D__SDCC_REVISION=11528 -D__SDCC_mcs51 -D__STDC_NO_COMPLEX__=1 -D__STDC_NO_THREADS__=1 -D__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__=1 -D__STDC_NO_VLA__=1 -D__STDC_ISO_10646__=201409L -D__STDC_UTF_16__=1 -D__STDC_UTF_32__=1 -isystem /usr/bin/../share/sdcc/include/mcs51 -isystem /usr/share/sdcc/include/mcs51 -isystem /usr/bin/../share/sdcc/include -isystem /usr/share/sdcc/include  ../../include/debug.c 
+ /usr/bin/sdas8051 -plosgffw debug.rel debug.asm
sdcc main.rel debug.rel -V -mmcs51 --model-small --xram-size 0x0400 --xram-loc 0x0000 --code-size 0x3800 -I/home/zico/Desktop/ch552tool/ch554_sdcc/examples/../include -DFREQ_SYS=24000000  -o blink.ihx
+ /usr/bin/sdld -nf blink.lk
objcopy -I ihex -O binary blink.ihx blink.bin
wchisptool -g -f blink.bin
```

Can't find any suitable USB device!

Also, the datasheet (5) was not helpful to me, even after translating it to English.

What I've tested so far:

- The USB wire I'm using does have data lines. Otherwise, Windows
  wouldn't tell me the device wasn't recognized.
- The USB wire is
  providing 5v. (Multimeter)
- The device is at least partially working, as the 3.3v output is in fact 3.3v.

At this point, I don't know how to figure out what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Edit 1: Added the text of the error from running `make flash`.
Edit 2: Added image of power and ground connections to USB.

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... post the actual text

Comment: @jsotola I added the text. To my eye, that text isn't helpful except to say that it failed. The rest is just standard make output.

Comment: The advantage of including the actual text, instead of a screenshot, is that search engines can search your actual text. That could be helpful for the next reader who has a similar problem.

Comment: Looks like your usb ground is not connected to anything

Comment: @Mike It's connected under the port. Sorry, I realize that was unclear. I added an image showing it.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I found the problem. I soldered a new chip to a new breakout board, and everything worked... classic. Anyways, thanks to everyone who tried to help. I'll close this question down.

Comment: Zico - Hi, Thanks for coming back with the answer to your question. In order to mark the topic as solved, please "accept" your answer (click the "tick mark" next to your answer, to turn it green). Then it is shown as having an accepted answer in various lists, and we don't get nagged for it being a question with an unaccepted answer. BUT on Stack Exchange sites [you must wait 48 hours after you asked the question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) before you can accept your own answer. So please come back in a couple of days to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: In case of breadboard prototypes, the problem is in approximately 100% of the cases some breadboard connection. In which case the solution is to solder the parts to some experiment board instead.